# MeCab Import Error when running python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, mecab

I have tried to make use of some code, I had set up before in a python file.
However, I run in an error.
If I use mecab in terminal it works as expected:

```
% mecab
君の名は
君   名詞,代名詞,一般,*,*,*,君,キミ,キミ
の   助詞,連体化,*,*,*,*,の,ノ,ノ
名   名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,名,ナ,ナ
は   助詞,係助詞,*,*,*,*,は,ハ,ワ
EOS
```

If I run MeCab in this script, it's getting an import error:

```
import MeCab
sent ="君の名は"
tagger = MeCab.Tagger()
print(tagger.parse(sent))
```

(I have also tried versions, where I defined the path for the dictionaries (and tried several ones, unidic, ipadic, neologd) `'-d /opt/homebrew/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic'`

The error I get is quite common and I found a lot of attempts to fix it online, none of which have been working for me:

```
ImportError
dlopen(/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MeCab/_MeCab.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN5MeCab11createModelEPKc'
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/importMeCab.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MeCab
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MeCab/_MeCab.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN5MeCab11createModelEPKc'
```

One [suggestion](https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS/issues/2210) was to build everything from source again. (I did, it still didn't work for the python script)

Other [suggestions](https://qiita.com/shimajiroxyz/items/b119caca98e056134792) [were](https://qiita.com/G1998G/items/2ad1b62c0285e478bfab) to upgrade pip and check with otool for the expected files

```
    /usr/lib/libmecab.dylib 
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib 
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

```
otool -L /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MeCab/_MeCab.cpython-311-darwin.so
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MeCab/_MeCab.cpython-311-darwin.so (architecture x86_64):
        @loader_path/../mecab-python3.dylibs/libmecab.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.23.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MeCab/_MeCab.cpython-311-darwin.so (architecture arm64):
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1300.23.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
```

and reassign the path from /usr/lib/ to the actual one (just as the author I only found `libmecab.dylib` in the `/opt/homebrew/lib` folder) with `% install_name_tool -change "expected path" [actual-path] /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MeCab/_MeCab.cpython-311-darwin.so`
and so it worked for the author, but I still receive the error.

I have also seen this [guide](https://You%20can%20always%20recompile%20your%20libraries%20and%20make%20them%20match%20each%20other.), but am unsure how to make the libraries "match" as suggested in the best rated answer.

Specs:

```
Mac Ventura 13.3.1 M1 Chip
MeCab 0.996
MeCab-Python3 1.0.6
Python 3.11.1 (through pyenv)
Unidic 1.1.0
```